# Retain desktop shortcut position on major upgrade in WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

My WiX installer optionally creates a desktop shortcut upon installation and removes it when it is uninstalled, a `CREATEDESKTOPSHORTCUT` property handles that, so nothing special so far.

When a major upgrade is performed, the shortcut is removed and recreated, resetting its position on the desktop to the first free spot. This is the default major upgrade behaviour, but how can I retain its position?

An obvious first approach involves using the `WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED` property which is only present if a major upgrade is running (I only use major upgrades). The desired behaviour is

- Create a shortcut on the initial installation if the product is not yet installed and `CREATEDESKTOPSHORTCUT` is true
- Don't touch the shortcut on a major upgrade (e.g. if `WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED` is present), regardless if it had been created on the initial installation or not
- Remove the shortcut when the product is uninstalled and if it had been created on the initial installation

Is there a way to achieve that? I guess it might boil down to a `Condition` element inside the shortcut's `Component` or `Feature`, but I don't get it up and running.

**Edit:**

One possible approach is to make the shortcut creating component permanent and introduce an additional component that is only triggered when the product is removed (and not major upgraded) and explicitly removes the link file from the desktop:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">
    <Component Id="CreateDesktopLink" Guid="My-GUID-1" Permanent="yes">
       <RegistryValue ... />
       <Shortcut Id="CmdShortcut" Name="My Desktop Link" Target="[SystemFolder]cmd.exe" />
    </Component>
    <Component Id="RemoveDesktopLink" Guid="My-GUID-2">
      <RegistryValue ... />
      <RemoveFile Id="RemoveDesktopLinkFile" Name="My Desktop Link.lnk" On="uninstall" />
      <Condition>REMOVE=ALL AND NOT WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED</Condition>
    </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

although that would leave an orphaned component behind on uninstall. Optionally, I could move the shortcut creation into a custom action, eliminating the permanent component.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about sequencing your "RemoveExistingProducts" standard action after InstallFinalize?

Doing so would mean that the newer product is installed followed by an uninstall of the older product. When the newer product is installed, the reference count of the component creating the shortcut will get incremented to 2 and hence when the older product is uninstalled, the component creating the shortcut would be untouched.

I am just thinking that this is one other possible solution.

However, re-sequencing "RemoveExistingProducts" is something which you will have to think through deeply.

Answer (score 0):

You can't preserve the shortcut - at least not in the default case of advertised shortcuts. These shortcuts contain a reference to the product, component and feature, and sometimes an icon that may be in the binary table of the cached MSI. At least two of these will change over an upgrade.

That leaves you with non-advertised shortcuts or ones you create yourself, for which attempting to preserve the location might work.

Perhaps you could enumerate the desktop icons (a search has code examples) so you can put the icon back where it was before, because that would work for all flavors of shortcut and you wouldn't need to change your upgrade logic. Just find out where it currently is, then find it again after it's installed and move it the original location.